# reshaping data frame and applying calculation for each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'family' : ["A","A","B","B"],
  'V1' : [5,5,40,10,],
  'V2' :[50,10,180,20],
  'gr_0' :["all","all","all","all"],
  'gr_1' :["m1","m1","m2","m3"],
  'gr_2' :["m12","m12","m12","m9"],
  'gr_3' :["NO","m14","m15","NO"]
                           })
```

and I would like to transform it in the following way:

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame({ 'family' : ["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"],
  'gr' : ["all","m1","m12","m14","all","m2","m3","m12","m9","m15"],
  "calc(sumV2/sumV1)":[6,6,6,2,4,4.5,2,4.5,2,4.5]            
               })
```

```
  family   gr  calc(sumV2/sumV1)
0      A  all                6.0
1      A   m1                6.0
2      A  m12                6.0
3      A  m14                2.0
4      B  all                4.0
5      B   m2                4.5
6      B   m3                2.0
7      B  m12                4.5
8      B   m9                2.0
9      B  m15                4.5
```

In order to reach to df_new:

1. I want the rows to be aligned by "family" X each unique value of "gr_" columns.
2. For every line to calculate the respective sum(V2)/sum(V1) as shown in the df_new.

I am quite new to python. Softcoding of this seems quite complex to me.
Preferably, I don't want "No" records to be listed in this df_new but it can stay in the output as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with this:

```
df_new = df.melt(id_vars=['family','V1','V2']).groupby(['family','value'])
                .apply(lambda x: x.V2.sum()/x.V1.sum())
                .reset_index(name='calc(sumV2/sumV1)')
df_new = df_new[df_new.value != 'NO'].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_new)

     family value  calc(sumV2/sumV1)
0      A    all           6.0
1      A    m1            6.0
2      A    m12           6.0
3      A    m14           2.0
4      B    all           4.0
5      B    m12           4.5
6      B    m15           4.5
7      B    m2            4.5
8      B    m3            2.0
9      B    m9            2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Ben.T :)

Answer (score 1):

#### `melt` + `groupby`:

```
v = df.melt(id_vars=['family','V1','V2'], value_name='gr')
w = v.loc[v.gr != 'NO']
x = w.groupby(['family', 'gr']).sum()

(x.V2 / x.V1).reset_index(name='calc(sumV2/sumV1)')
```

```
  family   gr  calc(sumV2/sumV1)
0      A  all                6.0
1      A   m1                6.0
2      A  m12                6.0
3      A  m14                2.0
4      B  all                4.0
5      B  m12                4.5
6      B  m15                4.5
7      B   m2                4.5
8      B   m3                2.0
9      B   m9                2.0
```

---

A similar approach to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53323971/3483203), but with the benefit of being fully vectorized, and avoiding `apply`

---

***Performance***:

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 1000, (1_000_000, 7))
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['family', 'V1', 'V2', 'gr_0', 'gr_1', 'gr_2', 'gr_3'])   
df[['gr_0', 'gr_1', 'gr_2', 'gr_3']] = df[['gr_0', 'gr_1', 'gr_2', 'gr_3']].astype(str)

%%timeit
v = df.melt(id_vars=['family','V1','V2'], value_name='gr')
w = v.loc[v.gr != 'NO']
x = w.groupby(['family', 'gr']).sum()    
(x.V2 / x.V1).reset_index(name='calc(sumV2/sumV1)')

2.71 s ± 32.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df_new = (df.melt(id_vars=['family','V1','V2']).groupby(['family','value'])
                 .apply(lambda x: x.V2.sum()/x.V1.sum())
                 .reset_index(name='calc(sumV2/sumV1)'))
df_new = df_new[df_new.value != 'NO'].reset_index(drop=True)

5min 24s ± 3.35 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @AlexandreNixon similar in approach, but I just added timings to show why `apply` should really be avoided.  Vectorized operations make a *big* difference